# In spring are all the beans created at the time of container creation

Tags: spring, spring-bean

If I have 1000 bean configurations in .xml file are all these beans created at the time of creation of the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default yes. All beans get created on startup. There's the `@Lazy` annotation which allows you to delay the initialization until the bean gets used.

Comment: You can also use the scope of bean to configure specific behavior:
- Prototype: the bean will be created each time needed.
- Session: each time you create a new Http session.
- Request each time you get a new Http request.
They are many possibilities but use it with caution to avoid memory leak